# Driving Duration and Distance - Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-maps

I have a connection to a SQL database through and load my data into a pandas dataframe. 
Roughly 10.000 rows of data. I have two columns containing addresses; one column containing 'Destination' and one column for 'Origin'.

I have been trying to figure out way to use the google maps API to get the distance from a-b and iterate through each row.

I have a dataframe df containing my data. 
df['Destination'] contains the destinations and df['Origin'] starting point.

Using below i can get a destination and duration into a json, but I'm stuck in extracting only the duration and distance for the route and then iterating through 10.000 rows while still being aware of the API limits from google maps.

```
import requests, json 
api_key = 'abcd'
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?' 
origin= 'Input from Dataframe'
destination = 'Input from Dataframe' 
navrequest = 'origin={}&destination={}&key={}'format(origin,destination,api_key) 
request = url + navrequest 
r = requests.get(request) 
x = r.json() 
print(x)
```

Now if I do above then I get the entire json output for one route, but I would like to loop over all rows and get the total duration for the trip and distance (km), and then save those outputs to the dataframe in two new columns.

Any inputs on this? Much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm almost positive this will exceed the Google API limits unless you have a subscription, and even then...

Comment: I have an API subscription, and will go under the limit per day. It'll take a few days to run all the rows.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of a matrix, but you're just doing 10000 queries. What are the limits you're concerned about, then? Is it queries per second?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend a self-hosted instance of OSRM. If you're on Linux, it's a 10 min setup and generally good enough. What, specifically, are you relying on the Google API to include? Traffic?

Comment: Using Windows. OSM could also work. Just need distance and duration between the two addresses.

Comment: I'm aware I'm well off from your initial question, but from experience I'd say create a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04, install OSRM on the VM and bridge the port (5000 IIRC) so you can query it from Windows. No limits, and it's faster than Google. I wouldn't try installing on Windows, I think they dropped support.